# Expression expected error on Volley requests

Tags: java, android, android-volley, android-context

I am getting an error called expression expected inside the bracket in this line.     `Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity);` . This class is on another activity other than my MainActivity. Here is the snippet of my code:

```
    public void youFunctionForVolleyRequest(final ServerCallbackJava callback) {

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity);

    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=22.2913,113.947&destinations=WanChai&mode=driving&key="REMOVED";

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    callback.onSuccess(response); // call call back function here

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //VolleyLog.d("Volley error json object ", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    })

    {
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType ()
        {
            return "application/json";
        }
    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    queue.add(jsonObjReq);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the help of following code snippet :

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                request r = new request(Main2Activity.this);
                r.youFunctionForVolleyRequest();
            }
        });
    }

   class request{

       Context ctx;
       public request(Context mContext) {
           ctx = mContext;
       }

       public void youFunctionForVolleyRequest() {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx);

        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=22.2913,113.947&destinations=WanChai&mode=driving&key=";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
        {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
               // callback.onSuccess(response); // call call back function here
                System.out.println("success");
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //VolleyLog.d("Volley error json object ", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                System.out.println("failed");
            }
        })

        {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType ()
            {
                return "application/json";
            }
        };
        // Adding request to request queue
        queue.add(jsonObjReq);
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: that is what i was explaining. Good job @ysl

Answer (score 1):

As you have created a class inside a activity/fragment, while calling the class you must pass the context of the activity and same pass to this function and replace the **RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity);** with **RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);** the declared context inside your class.

Answer (score 0):

make global variable in class VolleyRequests

```
Context context;
```

and initialize it on constructor

```
public VolleyRequests(Context mcontext) { this.context= mcontext; }
```

then use this

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
```

when you call it in MainActivity use :

```
VolleyRequests volleyrequests = new VolleyRequests (this);
```

Comment: Not working. Says "Cannot resolve method `getApplicationContext()` "

Comment: try RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

Comment: make global variable in class VolleyRequests Context context; and initialize it on constructor
public VolleyRequests(Context mcontext) {
this.context= mcontext;
},  then use this 
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context );
when you call it in MainActivity use : 
VolleyRequests  volleyrequests = new VolleyRequests (this)

Comment: my answer was Updated

Answer (score 0):

If your code in `Activity.class`:

`RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);//or
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Activity.this);//or
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());`

If your code in `Fragment.class`:

`RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());//or
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());//or
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Fragment.this.getContext());//or
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Fragment.this.getApplicationContext());`

Comment: What class is it located in?

Comment: I created another class called VolleyRequests, and the function above is inside this class

Comment: So the VolleyRequests is not an activity of android application. So it won't have context which you cannot call this or getApplicationContext() for the context. Because context existed in only activity class which extends from AppCompat or AppCompatActivity.

Comment: So you must create a setter in your custom class to set context from you activity or fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Inside that new class constructor, pass the context so that you use it with volley.

```
public class ClassWithVolley{
private Context context;
public ClassWithVolley(Context context){
this.context = context;
}
// continue
```